# Not able to run C++ application built with VS2017 on another machine where VS2017 is not installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have VS2017 installed on windows 10 machine and I am building my C++ code in it. when build success I am able to run that exe on same machine. But when I am copying that exe (with all dependent DLL's) on another winodws 10 machine where VS2017 is not installed its giving error **"The code execution cannot proceed because urctbase.dll was not found"**.

I copied those dll's (ucrtbase.dll vcrutime140.dll etc.) at the same location where exe resides and try to run it then its giving error **"The application was unable to start correctly(0xc700000b). Click OK to close the application"**

I installed VC Redistributable-2017 package to setup run time environment on that machine, but problem persists.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to make sure you've accounted for all your DLL dependencies.

Comment: You can use dependency walker to get more info about load dependencies

Comment: Don'y copy the dlls, but install them properly: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: One cause for this kind of problem is copying or installing a DEBUG build on the target machine, instead of a RELEASE build.  The debug related DLLs are not part of the VC Redistributable 2017 package.

Comment: Also be aware the there are separate 32 and 64 bit versions for the VC redistributables.

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to get all the dependent DLLs of your program. I suggest you create `setup project` that can detect all these dependencies:

**0-** Put your project in `release` mode
**1-** install `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects` from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)
**2-** Add setup project to your `VS solution`

[image]

**3-** Add your program to the setup project

[image]

**4-** Choose primary output of your project

[image]

**5-** As you can see, visual studio detect all dll dependencies
[image]